# Swift Image gallery with fullscreen slider

Tags: ios, arrays, image, swift, gallery

I want to build a facebook-like image gallery but don't know where to start from.
Here's what i think i should do:

- CollectionView that shows thumbnails based on an array
- On row-click, i modally open a pageViewController based on the same array of images
- On Swipe left-right, i go to the next or previous image
- On Swipe up-down, i close this view and go back to my collectionview

Is this logic correct/the best practice?
Maybe it's been already done by someone.

Comment: Sounds about right. Go for it dude

Comment: Thank you! is this the best approach? are there any open source script that already does this? I think it's a common need, but can't find any similar controls

Comment: You don't need thumbnails any more in IOS8 with Photos.framework, see [the sample Gallery from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html). Be modern~

Comment: This is in obj-c, i want to use swift, Carrl

Answer (score 1):

You can use banana library for showing images in slider view in Swift

get banana from https://github.com/gauravkatoch007/banana

```
import banana

@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!

// Here imageArray can be a string array of Image URLs 
var imageArray = [String]()

//or imageArray can be a array of UIImages
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

var imageScroll = banana( imageScrollView :self.imageScrollView )
//Load to load images in memory and display them in User Interface
imageScroll!.load(imageArray)

//Call startScroll for autoScrolling. Default scrolling timer is 8 seconds
imageScroll!.startScroll()


//Call this function to stop autoScrolling on touch or swipe.
imageScroll!.assignTouchGesture()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** I resolved in this way:

- Gallery is a collection view
- On cell selected, i modally segue to another view, which contains a scrollview in which i put 5 images one (right) after the other, and handle paginating.
- My image will always be the third in the middle, after every scroll, i choose the 5 images of my entire array which centers the index, or the 5 which contain this.

here's my class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
var screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var blackView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var photoActions: UIImageView!

var img1:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())
var img2:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())
var img3:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())
var img4:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())
var img5:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())

var w1: UIImage!
var w2: UIImage!
var w3: UIImage!
var w4: UIImage!
var w5: UIImage!
var pageIndex: Int!
var currentPage: Int!
var oldPage: Int!
var endFrame: CGRect!
var arrayIndex: Int!

// placeholder for if the image frame is scrolled
var scrolledPhotoFrame: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    RightSize()
    LoadData()
}

func LoadData(){
    // data passed from feedViewController gets stored here
    img1.image = w1
    img2.image = w2
    img3.image = w3
    img4.image = w4
    img5.image = w5
    // set the right endFrame based on the selectedImage

    switch pageIndex {
    case 0:
        img1.frame = endFrame
        img1.frame.origin.x = 0
    case 1:
        img2.frame = endFrame
        img2.frame.origin.x = screenSize.width
    case 2:
        img3.frame = endFrame
        img3.frame.origin.x = (screenSize.width * 2)
    case 3:
        img4.frame = endFrame
        img4.frame.origin.x = (screenSize.width * 3)
    case 4:
        img5.frame = endFrame
        img5.frame.origin.x = (screenSize.width * 4)
    default:
        break
    }
    currentPage = pageIndex
    oldPage = pageIndex

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width*5, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(pageIndex * Int(screenSize.width))
    println(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    // default value of scrolledPhotoFrame is unscrolled position of photoImageView
    scrolledPhotoFrame = endFrame

    // required for registering scroll events
    scrollView.delegate = self
   // RightSize()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func doneDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// called while scrolling
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / screenSize.width)
    if (currentPage != oldPage){
        //Ho cambiato pagina
        if (currentPage>oldPage){
            //Sono andato di 1 foto avanti
            println("Avanti")
            arrayIndex = arrayIndex+1
            CambioPagina()

        }else{
            //Sono andato di 1 foto indietro
            arrayIndex = arrayIndex-1
            println("indietro")
        }

        oldPage=currentPage
    }
    var alpha = CGFloat(1 - abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) / 100)
    var alpha2 = CGFloat(1 - abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) / 20)

    blackView.alpha = alpha
    doneButton.alpha = alpha2
    photoActions.alpha = alpha2
}

// This method is called right as the user lifts their finger
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    var offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    var alpha = CGFloat(1 - abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) / 240)

    if (abs(offsetY) > 100) {
        scrolledPhotoFrame.origin.y = scrolledPhotoFrame.origin.y - offsetY
        blackView.hidden = true
        scrollView.hidden = true // could be wrong
        doneButton.hidden = true
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// selecting the view to zoom
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    switch currentPage {
    case 0:
        return img1
    case 1:
        return img2
    case 2:
        return img3
    case 3:
        return img4
    case 4:
        return img5
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!) {
    img2.hidden = true
    img3.hidden = true
    img4.hidden = true
    img5.hidden = true
}

func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!, atScale scale: CGFloat) {

}

//Controllo per cambio pagina..! chissa!
func CambioPagina(){
    switch arrayIndex{
    case 0:
        w1 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex])
        w2 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+1])
        w3 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+2])
        w4 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+3])
        w5 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+4])
        pageIndex = 0
    case 1:
        w1 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-1])
        w2 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex])
        w3 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+1])
        w4 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+2])
        w5 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+3])
        pageIndex = 1
    case (arrayFoto.count-2):
        w1 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-3])
        w2 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-2])
        w3 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-1])
        w4 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex])
        w5 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+1])
        pageIndex = 3
    case (arrayFoto.count-1):
        w1 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-4])
        w2 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-3])
        w3 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-2])
        w4 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-1])
        w5 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex])
        pageIndex = 4
    default:
        w1 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-2])
        w2 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex-1])
        w3 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex])
        w4 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+1])
        w5 = UIImage(named: arrayFoto[arrayIndex+2])
        pageIndex = 2
    }
    LoadData()
}
func RightSize(){
    img1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.addSubview(img1)
    img2.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.width, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.addSubview(img2)
    img3.frame = CGRect(x: (screenSize.width*2), y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.addSubview(img3)
    img4.frame = CGRect(x: (screenSize.width*3), y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.addSubview(img4)
    img5.frame = CGRect(x: (screenSize.width*4), y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    scrollView.addSubview(img5)
    img1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    img2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    img3.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    img4.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    img5.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
}
```

Any better approach will be great, for example, i cannot handle image zoom

Comment: What happens if you have n-images? Better use ```UICollectionView```.